# Wildfly servers are not listed in eclipse even after installing JBOSS tools

Tags: eclipse, jboss, wildfly, jboss-tools, eclipse-marketplace

**Environment:**

- Eclipse Mars
- Linux v.?
- Java jdk v.?
- Wildfly v.?

I installed JBOSS tools from market place, the only version listed was JBoss tools 4.3.0 Beta and I installed it.

I restarted the eclipse. When I tried to add runtime environment in the view I could only see the servers related to Apache, Basic and Object Web but no servers related to either JBoss/Wildfly community are listed.

But the same steps worked in Windows' Eclipse Mars.

In Linux, I even tried 'Download additional server adapters' link in eclipse which gave options for many servers like Websphere, Oracle web logic but no options for JBoss/Wildfly.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the JBoss tools in Mars requires Java 8.

Run the eclipse using Java 8 and it will work. You can change eclipse.ini

In **Linux**

```
-vm
/your_jdk_home/bin/java
```

In **Windows**

```
-vm
/your_jdk_home/bin/javaw.exe
```

**Remember**,

-vm argument should not come after -vmargs.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I have started eclipse using oracle jdk 8 but jboss tools is still not showing

Comment: @sashok_bg have you fixed it? I'm still facing the same problem.

Comment: @AirtonGessner did you try to run your eclipse with Java 8?

Comment: @AirtonGessner I know it's a "no solution" solution but I just went and bought IntelliJ.. never looked back

Comment: @pinkpanther yep. But I solved it by changing from Eclipse Neon to Mars. I'm still kinda noob in eclipse so I migth have done something wrong.

Comment: @AirtonGessner that could be because of Eclipse compatibility "JBoss Tools is now targeting Eclipse Mars.1 as a running platform." see http://tools.jboss.org/documentation/whatsnew/jbosstools/4.3.0.Final.html#eclipse-compatibility

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem and I solved it.

- First go to Help-Eclipse Marketplace. There in the search option
- Type JBoss Tools. Then the jsboos tools appear
- Install it and it will ask to restart the eclipse
- Restart Eclipse
- Go to the add server option. There you can see as shown in the picture below [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhmum.png)
- Click on JBoss AS, wildfly& EAP server tools and click next. Tt will install the server configuration and then if it asks to restart eclipse after installing, do restart
- After restart go to add server. In the list at JBoos community, you can see the wildfly server installed

Please do commented here if any queries.